# Break line after full stop when words near to 800

Tags: php

I have a long description , i want to break the string after every full stop when word count is greater then 800 .

Like count 800 characters THEN idenify the next occurrence of a ‘.’ break the line look for next 800 words then a full stop and then break the line again .

```
function TrimString($String, $Length){
    if(strlen($String)<=$Length){
        $stringValue=$String;
    } else {
        $new_l = strpos ($String , ".", $Length);
        $Length = $new_l+1;
        $stringValue=substr($String,0,$Length);
    }
    return $stringValue;
}
```

i tried using this function but not working as expected .

```
$m=800;
echo TrimString(stripslashes($content),$m);
```

Thanks in advance for your help .

Comment: And what is not working here? (it seems working to me:- https://eval.in/812367)

Comment: I didn't see any break line sequence / character ?

Comment: my string is of 1 million words and i want to break my string after each 800 words after the next occurrence of full stop . then look for next 800 words and break when next full stop is found :).

Answer (score 2):

I understand your question like:
Search for the first `.` after each 800 signs and insert a `new line`.
If it's correct, so you have to loop through your string in your method like this example

```
function trimString($string, $length){
    $str_length = strlen($string);

    if ($str_length <= $length){
        return $string;
    }

    $from = 0;
    $string_value = '';

    // max amount of loops based on the length of $string and $length
    $loops = ceil($str_length / $length);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $loops; $i++) {
        // $from could be 0 or the length of your last finding dot
        $tmp_length = $from + $length;

        if ($tmp_length > $str_length) {
            break;
        }

        // get the position of the dot after the calculated length
        $pos = strpos($string , ".", $tmp_length);

        // append the dot and a br-tag for a new line
        $string_value .= substr(substr($string, 0, $pos), $from) . ".<br/>";

        // set to the next position after the finding dot
        $from = $pos + 1;
    }

    return $string_value;
}

echo trimString("This is a test. This is not a test. This is a new test.", 5);
```

### Update #1

Because I was running in some errors with the function above I've made a new example and tested it with these cases. Now the last occurence of `$search` will be noticed too.
I hope this will help you

```
function trimString($haystack, $length, $search, $insert = ''){
    $str_length = strlen($haystack);

    if ($str_length <= $length){
        return $haystack;
    }

    $from = 0;
    $string_value = '';
    $search_after = $length;

    // find the last position of $search in the string
    $pos_last_dot = strrpos($haystack, $search);

    while ($search_after <= $pos_last_dot) {
        // get the position of $search after the last position
        $pos = strpos($haystack , $search, $search_after);

        // append the $search and the $insert for a new line
        $string_value .= substr(substr($haystack, 0, $pos), $from) . $search . $insert;

        // set the cursor to the next position after the finding $search
        $from = $pos + 1;

        // add the last occurence of $search
        if (($from + $length) >= $pos_last_dot && $pos != $pos_last_dot) {
            $string_value .= substr(substr($haystack, 0, $pos_last_dot), $from) . $search . $insert;
            break;
        }

        $search_after = $from + $length;
    }

    return $string_value;
}

echo trimString("This is a test. This is not a test. This is a new test This is a new test. foo. bar.", 10, ".", "<br/>");
```

Comment: Thanks my friend , i think it is working as expected what i can see in first view .

Comment: Yea no problem, if this is the answer of your question than mark it like that @phpdev

Comment: a faced a problem in that , if the last remaining characters are less then 800 then it skips that part .  Ex a string has 1800 words it shows 1600 and skips the remaining 200 word , need your help on that please .

Comment: I tried and made some changes in function and it is working as expected . i tried getting value of the floor and then run the remaining string . is my logic correct ? .@UfguFugullu

Comment: I've made an update of this function which will notice the last occurence of the `$search` @phpdev

Comment: This will break if the input text has HTML characters with '.' . for ex. if text has img path then and if length reaches to img path with having extension .jpg then it will break